# Specifying permissions for CRUD operations using RBAC

Tags: crud, nested-sets, rbac

I work with a hierarchy of objects using [Nested Sets model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model). I want to set permissions for CRUD operations on a single object. As a system for managing access rights I use PHP RBAC. How I can solve this problem?

After some analysis of the problem, I decided that it is possible to create four permissions trees for each CRUD operation on object and get each permission individualy, but I think that it is not a best solution.

As an alternative, I thought about using a single premissions tree, which nodes correspond to the operation "read", and each node has child elements "create", "update" and "delete", but I'm not sure that this model can be implemented using PHP RBAC.

Any suggestions or references to materials are welcome. I am sure that on this subject there is material that I have not yet found.

Answer (score 2):

RBAC is likely not enough here because you have:

- a hierarchy of resources
- different actions
- potential relationships between the users and the resources.

To implement your scenario, you can use RBAC and extend it using ABAC (attribute based access control). With ABAC, you achieve the following benefits:

- you externalize the authorization logic to a central policy decision point
- you express the authorization logic as policies instead of roles
- the policies can use any attribute of the user, resource, action, and context

You can express the following scenarios in ABAC:

- a user with the role==manager can do the action==edit on a document if the document.location==user.location

XACML, the eXtensible Access Control Markup Language implements ABAC. You can read more on XACML and ABAC here:

- ABAC: [NIST project page](http://csrc.nist.gov/projects/abac/).
- [XACML introduction & architecture](http://developers.axiomatics.com/blog/index/entry/xacml-reference-architecture.html).